# Vuetify: editing no-data-text prop or no-data slot for v-select doesn't seem to have any effect

Tags: nuxt.js, vuetify.js, v-select, no-data

I'm using Vuetify in a Nuxt project. By using the slot `no-data` in a `v-data-table` I was able to modify the "No data available" message. It's also working if I use the prop `no-data-text`.

```
<v-data-table>
  <template slot="no-data">
    My no data message
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

OR

```
<v-data-table no-data-text="My no data message"></v-data-table>
```

As the documentation of the v-select shows the same prop and slot, I tried to update the message as well but I still have "No data available" showing instead of my own message.
Am I doing something wrong?

The only other subject I found which might be related is https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/2081

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad, might have some issue with cache or something else. I can see my message. Well this question might still help the one who are wondering how to update the no-data message or to translate it, as I looked for it a while. ><

Answer (score 5):

You can use the v-bind syntax if the no data text will change based on some condition

```
 <v-data-table :no-data-text="no_results_text">   
 </v-data-table>

<script>
export default {
  data:function(){
    return {
      no_results_text: "test message"
    }
  }, 
  methods: {
   updateText(){
     this.no_results_text="other message"
   }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Sunday Ømwami code and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70937665/13559747), you can use the no-data slot.

```
<v-data-table ...>   
</v-data-table>

<template #no-data>
  {{ no_results_text }}
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data(){
    return {
      no_results_text: "test message"
    }
  }, 
  methods: {
   updateText(){
     this.no_results_text="other message"
   }
  }
}
</script>
```

Also, if you need to escape html content on no_results_text variable, you can use instead:

```
<template #no-data>
  <span v-html="no_results_text"></span>
</template>
```