# no-data section loads first and then shows the data in v-data-table

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am using vuetify v-data-table to display data. The issue I am facing here is No Settings Yet message always shows for like 1 second and then displays the data. Its like no data message loads first and then the actual data shows up. Is there a way to fix this.

```
<template>
  <div>
          <v-card>
              <v-data-table
                :headers="headers"
                :items="settings"
                hide-default-footer
                disable-pagination
                :mobile-breakpoint="0">

                <template slot="top" v-if="isLoading">
                  <v-progress-linear
                      indeterminate
                      color="red"
                  ></v-progress-linear>
                </template>

                <template slot="item" slot-scope="props">
                  <tr>
                    <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ props.item.value }}</td>
                </tr>
              </template>
              <template slot="no-data" >
                <v-alert id='no-data' :value="true" color="error" icon="warning">
                  No Settings Yet
                </v-alert>
              </template>
            </v-data-table>
          </v-card>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

  export default {
    data: function() {
      return {
        settings: [],
        headers: [
          { text: 'Name', value: 'name'},
          { text: 'Value', value: 'value'},
          { text: 'Actions', sortable: false}
        ],
        isLoading: false
      }
    },
    created() {
      this.fetchSettings();
    },
    
    methods: {
      fetchSettings() {
        var that = this;

        that.isLoading = true;
        this.$axios.get('/settings.json')
        .then(response => {
          that.settings = response.data;
          that.isLoading = false;
        });
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this by adding v-if directive in no-data slot like below example

```
            <template slot="no-data" v-if="!isLoading">
            <v-alert id='no-data' :value="true" color="error" 
               icon="warning">
              No Settings Yet
            </v-alert>
          </template>
```

Comment: I tried this then it return no data available message instead of no settings yet and then goes away after a second

Comment: hey @user12763413  i find this in documentation you have to use like this for slot  https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#slots       <template v-if="isEnabled('no-data')" v-slot:no-data>
    //your code </template>

Answer (score 2):

From the `v-data-table`'s point of view in your case there are only 2 states: **data is present** or **not** (yet). That's why `no-data` slot is always visible on loading.

If you want to show both "Loading" message and "No settings yet" alert in this slot, you can do it this way:

```js
<v-data-table
  :headers="headers"
  :items="desserts"
  :search="search"
  hide-default-footer
  disable-pagination
  :mobile-breakpoint="0"
>
  <template #top>
    <v-progress-linear
      v-show="isLoading"
      indeterminate
      color="red"
    />
  </template>
  <template #no-data>
    <v-alert v-show="!isLoading" :value="true" color="error" icon="warning">
      No Settings Yet
    </v-alert>
    <span v-show="isLoading">Loading...</span>
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

Check [this CodePen playground](https://codepen.io/betanet/pen/PoOZvVm) for a better understanding. There you'll also be able to understand the difference between `no-data` and `no-results` slots.